# I want to attach an outputstream to my vga port on my laptop using Java

Tags: java, image, outputstream, vga

I have to do a demonstration on my project progression next month. If I can display a simple image on a monitor through through the VGA port on my laptop, I would be very happy.

If someone could explain the amount of work that will be required to do this and where I should start, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Do you truly believe that streaming the bytes of an image file to the VGA port will make a monitor connected there show it? Suggest you learn how to write a [Java Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) program instead. Or maybe a JavaFX program.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need effectively need to write your own video card driver that sends display information to a monitor. I would not attempt to estimate the work as it takes teams of engineers to write drivers normally. I recommend as Andreas says write a Java Swing program that has a simple GUI and can show a map, or a picture of a butterfly